# What's the position vector for an ant on a sphere?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, differential-geometry, reference-frames, coordinate-systems

Imagine an ant on a sphere that perceives only two dimensions. Is there a coordinate system that allows the ant to describe the position with the position vector?

Comment: You need two angles: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system

Comment: No, the ant does't percepts 3 dimensions, it wants do describe a 2 dimensional curved space with 2 coordinates

Comment: Any grid should work. Coordinate values should not necessarily be angles refered to the centre. But it is just me visually depicting the situation.

Comment: The term "position vector" is not useful, or even defined, in curved space or spacetime.  We just call them _coordinates_.  Latitude and longitude will do fine.

Comment: m4r35n357, does it mean that the position vector makes sense only in flat space? Do you need a cartesian coordinate system to speak about position vector or it can be done also in polar coordinates?

Comment: I bet you have done this before, OP, just look at a world atlas :)

Comment: 1)  Just as in the plane, there are many local coordinate systems that will work to describe the ant's position.  2)  Unlike in the plane, there is no global coordinate system that will work to describe the ant's position.  3)  The ant's position is a point on a sphere.   A sphere is not a vector space.  So it's both weird and misleading to call the position a "position vector".